# In Laravel 9.0, passing data to view throws undefined variable exception

Tags: php, laravel, database, view, routes

I'm trying to pass data as a variable to a view in Laravel 9.0 & it's not working, but only in one specific situation. Basically, I want to do this, but for a different view:

```
Route::get('/lessons', function () {

  $terms = Term::all();

  return view('lessons', [
    'terms' => $terms
  ]);

});
```

Although the above code is fine, this isn't the view I want to pass data to. I have tried to do the same exact thing for the view I need, but Laravel is throwing an exception.

```
Route::get('/lessons/{lesson}', function ($slug) {

  $terms = Term::all();

  return view('lesson', [
    'lesson' => Lesson::find($slug),
    'terms' => $terms
  ]);

});
```

In this case, I'm getting an "Undefined variable $terms" exception. As you can see, the only difference is that in the second bit, another piece of data is being passed as well. It seems the function is ignoring the **$terms = Term::all();** declaration, but I'm not sure why. I'm a beginner in programming, so I'm sorry if the reason is very obvious.

EDIT: If it makes a difference, I'm calling the data with **{{ $terms->find('house')->definition }}** in a Blade component. Again, that same syntax works in "/lessons" but Laravel can't find **$terms** in "/lessons/01".

Comment: Can you [edit] to include the exact text of the error message you're seeing (_not_ a screenshot, just the full text). There might be additional information in there that doesn't mean much to you but can help someone else understand the problem.

Comment: The code you posted should expose a `$terms` variable to your `lesson.blade.php` file. Is there possibly another spot you're calling `view('lesson')` where you're _not_ passing `['terms' => ...]`? From my experience, this is the usual case for this error.